# How can I trigger the method on the component in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am just getting my head around components in reactjs. This is part of my component/container:

```js
onAddToCart(id) {
                console.log('testing onaddtocart')
                this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_TO_CART', id: id});
            }
        
render() {
        
                var Packs = [];
                if (this.props.packsData != undefined && this.props.packsData.existingFoxtelPackage != undefined) {
                    if (this.props.packsData.existingFoxtelPackage.eligiblePacks.length > 0) {
                        Packs = this.props.packsData.existingFoxtelPackage.eligiblePacks;
                        console.log('testing=Packs', Packs);
                    }
                }
        
                return (
                    <div>hello from Packscontainer!!!
        
                        <div>
                            {
                                Packs.map(pack =>
                                    <Pack id={pack.id} name={pack.name} addToCart={this.onAddToCart.bind(this, pack.id)}/>
                                )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
}
```

The problem is that the onAddToCart method is not fired when clicking on the addToCart button, this is part of the Pack component:

```js
 render() {
        const { addToCart } = this.props
        return (
            <div>hello from pack
                {this.props.id} - {this.props.name}

                <button onClick={addToCart}>Add to cart</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

How can I trigger the onAddTocart method in the container?

Comment: if you print out `addToCart` or debug into `render` and see the value, is it a function or `undefined`? do you see any errors in the console complaining about `this` is `undefined` (since you didn't bind `addToCart`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now there was another issue with the page